# Add Additional Fields when Creating a Post within Wordpress Dashboard

Tags: wordpress

All,
I'm trying to create additional fields and I've done a little research on this already and found that you should use the add_meta_box().

However, I looked at the wordpress Codex but I'm not sure where I should implement this. Here is the link to that:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

I'm not sure which file I need to alter to add a simple text box. Can someone point me in the right direction to what file to update and what is a good way to go about doing this?

Ideally, I'd like to save this into a table. Is it better to create a custom table for this for upgrades of Wordpress? If you have any pointers on how to save the data that would be great as well!

Thanks so much for any advice you might have! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use this plugin. 
this is easy to use.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/verve-meta-boxes

Comment: Thanks for the plugin. Do you have an example of how to loop through the variables that I add so that I can add them to my database? I know it says Place <?php get_post_custom_values('your_custom_field_key_here'); ?> inside the Loop in your templates but not sure where to add this at.